# How to leave processes created by script executed via desktop shortcut launcher alive after it finishes the execution?

Tags: launcher, vpn

I would like to have an executable desktop shortcut that starts the VPN client, prompts me to provide a password and leaves the established connection alive until I run the second executable that disconnects it. I was able to do this, however, after the script ends (terminal closes) my VPN connection disappears with it. This is my desktop launcher file:

```
[Desktop Entry]

Version=1.0
Name[en_US]=F5 Start
GenericName[en_US]=F5 Start
Comment[en_US]=Start the VPN

#Exec=gnome-terminal -x bash -c "f5fpc -s -t https://remote.some_website.com -u user.name; sleep 30; f5fpc --info; sleep 5"
#Exec=gnome-terminal --window -x bash -c "f5fpc -s -t https://remote.some_website.com -u user.name"
Exec=gnome-terminal -- bash /home/user/Desktop/start.sh
Path=/home/user/Desktop/
Icon=f5-vpn-client

Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application
```

And the script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
f5fpc -s -t https://remote.some_website.com -u user.name
sleep 10
f5fpc --info
sleep 5
exit 0
```

When I do this manually everything works fine. I can exit the terminal and VPN connection stays established. Do you have any idea why does it happen and how can I change my approach so it would work the way I would like it to work?

Edit: I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do a bit of this sort of thing to open temporary NFS connections or Vaults of one sort or another.  I find it easiest to script both the open and close in the same bash script called by the launcher and separate them with a read from the console:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Perform "Open VPN" functions
read -p "Press return to close VPN..." REPLY
# Perform "Close VPN" functions
```

You can set the gnome-terminal position and geometry in the launcher so that it is out of the way until you need to close.

Comment: Thanks, this way of doing it does make sense for my use case too. However, I am not going to Accept your answer as I still would like to know the reason why is this happening and how to overcome it in the feature if I would need to start something else without leaving the terminal open.